# Getting Duplicate class error after Implementing the below Library-Android

Tags: java, android, jackson, duplicates, intuit-partner-platform

```
implementation ('com.intuit.quickbooks-online:ipp-v3-java-ata:6.2.0')
implementation (group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit', version: 
'6.2.0', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')
implementation (group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'oauth2-platform-api', version: 
'6.2.0', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')
```

Above are the dependencies I am using
AND
Below are the errors I am facing

```
Duplicate class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonAnnotation found in the following 
modules: jetified-ipp-v3-java-devkit-6.2-jar-with-dependencies.0-jar-with-dependencies 
(com.intuit.quickbooks-online:ipp-v3-java-devkit:6.2.0), jetified-jackson-annotations-2.9.0 
(com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0) and jetified-oauth2-platform-api-6.2- 
jar-with-dependencies.0-jar-with-dependencies (com.intuit.quickbooks-online:oauth2-platform- 
api:6.2.0)
```

Please help me out with the solution but didn't worked.

I have tried below solutions

1. Invalidate cache and Restart
2. Clean and Rebuild project
3. implementation ('com.intuit.quickbooks-online:ipp-v3-java-data:6.2.0') {
   exclude group: "com.sun.istack", module: "istack-commons-runtime"
   exclude group: "com.sun.xml.bind", module: "jaxb-impl"
   exclude group: "org.glassfish.jaxb", module: "jaxb-runtime"
   exclude group: "org.springframework", module: "spring-jcl"
   //exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
   exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpcore"
   exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: ""
   exclude group: "org.apache.http.impl.client", module: "jetified"

   ```
        }

        implementation (group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit', version: '6.2.0', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')
                {
                    exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpcore"
                    exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: ""
                    exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson", module: "jackson-annotations"

                }
        implementation (group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'oauth2-platform-api', version: '6.2.0', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')
                {
                    exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpcore"
                    exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: ""
                    exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson", module: "jackson-annotations"
                }
   ```

Comment: Exclude jackson from first one too "com.intuit.quickbooks-online:ipp-v3-java-ata:6.2.0" you are only doing it from devkit and oauth only

Comment: Tried now still having same issue